# cutycapt does not create links inside the pdf

Tags: qt, pdf, qtwebkit

I am using CutyCapt to create pdf from html, the issue is that the pdf does not contain links.
it removes all the links from the pdf. now I saw in that code that it creates object from type 
QWebFrame and then print that frame to the printer.

```
QWebFrame *mainFrame = mPage->mainFrame();
  QPainter painter;


case PdfFormat:
    case PsFormat: {
      QPrinter printer;
      printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
      printer.setOutputFileName(mOutput);
      // TODO: change quality here?
      mainFrame->print(&printer);
      break;
    }
```

Any idea, what I need to do on the QT side to enable links .